# Overwriting css declared width by Swiper in react

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I have a problem with my Swiper in react. I'm trying to set a responsive width for my SwiperSlides but no matter what I do, its always being overwritten and its set to maximum width.

I've tried css declaration, DOM Manipulation in useEffect and a bunch of thing on the Internet but I got no luck.

`"swiper": "6.8.2"`

DOM Manipulation:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 1536) {
      const wrapper = document.querySelector(
        'SOME_ID .swiper-container .swiper-wrapper',
      );
      const slides = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide');
      for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i += 1) {
        console.log(slides[i].style.width);
        slides[i].style.width = '90vw';
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

Swiper

```js
<Swiper
          pagination={pagination}
          spaceBetween={16}
          className="mySwiper"
          centeredSlides={true}
        >
          {list.map((ee) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={ee.id} style={{ width: '80vw' }}>
              // external component
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </Swiper>
```

CSS

```css
.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  opacity: 0.6;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  width: 80%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.swiper-slide {
  width: 80%;
}
```

NOTE: `centeredSlides={true}` was proposed in swiperjs.com.